# Google Analytics: Simultaneously running Classic and Universal Tracking

Tags: google-analytics, analytics, user-tracking

I recently needed to enable Demographics and Interest Reporting on a website which had already upgraded to the Universal tracking code.  Since the universal tracking code isn't set to support Demographic and Interest Reports until Phase 3, I decided to create a new Google Analytics property for the same site.

The site, [SEOcial](http://seocial.ly), is now simultaneously running the universal tracking code and the classic tracking code with Demographics and Interest Reporting enabled to two different Google Analytics Properties using the same url.  Should I manually change the Classic analytics property code to the same property as the universal analytics code?

I am a little concerned because I was unable to find a definitive answer to whether this would work or not.  I'd like to make sure this will not harm the site's statistics.  Has anyone done this before or something similar?  Can you please shed some light on what is the best way to enable demographic and interest reporting on a property using a universal analytics?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

don't change the Classic code UA property - it should be different from the Universal Analytics one. Keep it as you have it now.

For reference, check this video by GA Product Manager Nick Mihailovski (around 12')
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4tZIBg7vM-I

Comment: What will happen if I have classic GA and Universal GA on source code with same tracking code? Is data from both tracking code get collected in reports? I checked in debugger, both tracking codes are firing normally.

Answer (score 0):

Like Maggieto said, they should have unique UA IDs.  I am running classic and universal on a couple of our client sites at the moment and it does not affect the data.  However, I do see a discrepancy in the data reported by each implementation.

Are you seeing a discrepancy here as well? And if so, which implementation is reporting more traffic?

Comment: Yes, I am also seeing some discrepancies.

My Universal Analytics is reporting more Page Views ( 31,141 vs. 30,422)  since I've implemented both tracking codes, while the Classic Analytics reports more Unique Visits (10,403 vs, 10,253).