# Google Analytics Universal and Classic

Tags: google-analytics, universal-analytics

I have several different Google Analytics codes for several different purposes. With the one I recently created, GA automatically created it as Universal, without the option of Classic. However, I have several other trackers as Classic.

Is there a way to use both Google Analytics Universal and Classic codes on the same page?

I have too much to do a migration and change everything around, and need an option to use both codes on the same page.

Thanks for your help!...every time you help me you save a kitten!!

Comment: Here are some resources you can check out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21920188/google-analytics-simultaneously-running-classic-and-universal-tracking, https://community.jivesoftware.com/thread/251731

Answer (score 0):

The "classic" code will track to classic properties or, for the time being, to properties that have been recently transferred to Universal Analytics. UA code will track only to UA enabled properties.

You can mix classic and universal code on properties that have been recently transfered to UA (altough at the moment I cannot find the reference for that in the docs, plus I'm not sure how this will work with cross domain tracking).

[You can use both ga.ja and analytics.js without problems](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1032400?hl=en) if they track to different properties (again, this will give you problems with cross domain tracking since they use different parameters to transfer the session between domains).